# Counting inversions of 2D pair (x,y) in a list

Tags: python, inversion

The question is just like normal counting inversion question, but instead of a list of single numbers, now the input is a list of (x,y) pair.

For a list of pairs [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),...,(xn,yn)], a pair (i,j) is a inversion iff `i < j` and `xi>xj`, `yi>yj`. Is it possible to write the algorithm in O(n*logn*logn)? I tried several ways but during the merge step, each element from the right half of list has to compare with all elements in the left one, resulting in a time complexity of n square.

Comment: If it is the same question but with only pairs of ```int``` instead of ```int```, why would the standard algo fail?

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur  The standard algorithm works but with a cimplexity of N square. B/c for each merge&count step, you have to compare a (xj,yj) from the right part with all (xi,yi) from the left part. But I want to have a solution with a complexity of O(nlonlogn)

Answer (score 0):

Split the list into two halves, `left` and `right` based on the `x` coordinate. Then, compare the lowest point of the two halves (based on their `y` coordinate). There are two cases:

1. The left point is lower than the right point, then the left point has `xi<xj` and `yi<yj` for all the points on its right.
2. The right point is lower than left, so the `yi>yj` condition hold true for any point to its left.
   After updating you answer according to these 2 cases, you can remove one of these two points and continue working on the remaining sorted lists (by recursively solving for `left` and `right` as well). This should work in `O(nlog^2n)`

Comment: Abhinav, thanks for the reply! Just one quick problem. When you split the origin list into two halves, i.e. left and right, based on x values, this would mess up the ordering in the origin list right? And thus when you campared left point(xi) with right point(xj), there is no guarantee that i < j b/c now i,j are from a sorted list instead of origin list.

Comment: In the question, you haven't mentioned anything about the ordering on ```(i,j)```

Comment: Sry, my bad :( I'll update the description. The requirement is the same as standard counting inversion. index(i,j) is called a inversion iff i<j and xi>xj,yi>yj.

Comment: Where is this question posted? I'm pretty sure the question wouldn't ask for the ```i<j``` condition

Comment: It's a bonus question from a CS homework. But maybe it can use the knowledge of `half-inverted`, which is from previous part of the same question list. The `half-inverted pair` is defined as: `With a fixed constant y0 a pair (i,j) is called half-inverted if i < j, xi > xj, and yi >= y0 > yj`

Comment: Any constraints on the values of ```xi``` or ```yi```?

Comment: Nope. As long as they are from the list.